# MYSQL - create table contains empty general log

Tags: mysql

how do i create table that contains general log which is empty ?

i know u need to use

```
 set global general_log = 'on' ;
```

to enable the log

and

```
 set global log_output = 'table';
```

to set the log_output to table

so now ,how do i create table that contain empty general log ?

Comment: This has been answered here: Possible duplicate of https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10329/how-to-enable-mysql-general-log

Comment: @Macro but the link did not mention anything about empty general log ..

Comment: This part:
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `general_log` (
  `event_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `user_host` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `thread_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `server_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `command_type` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `argument` mediumtext NOT NULL
) ENGINE=CSV DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='General log'